# how to build ipa of flutter app without apple developer account

Tags: ios, flutter, ipa

I want to built ipa of flutter app without developer account. The app has a use for just 2 person.
Thats I don't want to purchase apple developer account. Is there any solution that we can built ipa without having the memebership apple developer account.

I didn't find any solution for this.

Comment: You can use a free developer account but you can only sign your app for a single device and you will need to install a new build every seven days. So, there isn't really a solution for your problem.

Comment: I want to publish on diawi. I just need ipa. The question is that can we built ipa without having developer account?

Comment: No.  You will need a developer account. A free developer account will only produce apps that are valid for 7 days and for a single device, so you will probably need a paid account.